# Drop the entries with lowest values in SQLite in place

Tags: sqlite

Let's consider the following table

```
CREATE TABLE t ( param INTEGER, te TEXT );
```

If we want to sort it by `param` (descending) and show its first 20 (biggest) entries we can do

```
SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY param DESC LIMIT 20;
```

If we want to save only those 20 rows we could do

```
ALTER TABLE t RENAME TO t_bak;
CREATE TABLE t (param INTEGER, te TEXT);
INSERT INTO t SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY param DESC LIMIT 20;
DROP t_bak
```

Can this be done in place (or at least in a less clumsy manner)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQLite (and in any other database that understands standard SQL), this can be done with a simple subquery:

```
DELETE FROM t
WHERE param NOT IN (SELECT param
                    FROM t
                    ORDER BY param DESC
                    LIMIT 20);
```

Comment: Are the braces required or are they only for legibility?

Comment: Subqueries always need parentheses. (And you could have just tested it.)